How to force Python multiple processes to share the same memory for one import
I am using the CPU version of PyTorch and need to spawn multiple processes with it. However, whenever I do import torch, a large chunk of memory is consumed (roughly 200 MB as of PyTorch 2.4.0+cpu). This is problematic if I would like to spawn a large number of processes that run PyTorch.
How could I avoid the memory waste by forcing multiple processes to share the same import torch, or alternatively, how could I find out what is consuming so much memory when I do import torch?
Given below is a small example that I have been using:
import multiprocessing as mp
import resource

m1 = resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss

import torch

m2 = resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss
delta = m2 - m1
print(delta)  # roughly 200 MB for torch==2.4.0+cpu


def f(x):
    print(resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss)  # roughly 134 MB
    return x * x


if __name__ == "__main__":
    mp.set_start_method("fork")
    with mp.Pool(5) as p:
        print(p.map(f, [1, 2, 3]))


The OS is key for this question. Which do you use?

I am using centos 7.
